# Jquery Mobile Dynamic data-role not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using JQM v1.1. Have declared a UL tag with data-role & data-theme on one of my data-role=page which is one of the pages (multi page doc).

```
<ul id="dailylistul" data-role="listview" data-theme="d">
```

have some code to inject the LI's as follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dailylisthref").click(function () {
$('#dailylistul').children().remove();
$('#dailylistul').attr('data-role', 'slide');
$('#dailylistul').attr('data-theme', 'd');
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };
  $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    //console.log("iteration " + val);
     $('#dailylistul').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
    })
    $.mobile.changePage("#dailylistpage", "slide");
})
```

This works fine except that the $('#dailylistul').attr('data-role', 'listview') does not happen after the first time. The remove() on the UL's children also removes the styles in UL. And it does not apply the styles being reset again in code the next time. Is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First when restting the data-role attribute you are setting it to slide, I'm assuming you meant listview.

That said I'm not sure why you are resetting the attributes on the list view, you should be able to just remove it's contents,
Something like

```
$("#dailylisthref").click(function () {
  $('#dailylistul').empty();
  var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };
    $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    //console.log("iteration " + val);
     $('#dailylistul').append('<li>' + val + '</li>');
    })
    $.mobile.changePage("#dailylistpage", "slide");
})
```

After modifying a JQM list (after you added the elements) you need to call it's refresh method. You also may need to call it before the page is shown, for example

```
$(document).delegate('#dailylistpage', 'pageshow', function () {
        $('#dailylistul').listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#dailylistul li').remove();
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {

 $('#dailylistul').append($('<li>' + val + '</li>'));
});
 $('#dailylistul').listview('refresh');
$.mobile.changePage("#dailylistpage", "slide");
```